# Reading Json Content and Displaying it

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I am deserializing JSON

> {
>   "topalbums":{
>   "album":[
>   {
>   "name":"Slumdog Millionaire",
>   "playcount":1442872,
>   "url":"https://www.last.fm/music/A.R.+Rahman/Slumdog+Millionaire",
>   "artist":{
>   "name":"A.R. Rahman",
>   "mbid":"e0bba708-bdd3-478d-84ea-c706413bedab",
>   "url":"https://www.last.fm/music/A.R.+Rahman"
>   },
>   "image":[
>   {
>   "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/14c3f3bc7834415db7765563177e4bf6.png",
>   "size":"small"
>   },
>   {
>   "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/14c3f3bc7834415db7765563177e4bf6.png",
>   "size":"medium"
>   },
>   {
>   "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/14c3f3bc7834415db7765563177e4bf6.png",
>   "size":"large"
>   },
>   {
>   "#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/14c3f3bc7834415db7765563177e4bf6.png",
>   "size":"extralarge"
>   }
>   ]
>   }
>   ]
>   }
>   }

```
string artist = txtMusic.Text;
var requestUrl = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=" + artist + "&api_key=&format=json";

var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 58.0.3029.110 Safari / 537.36");

var response = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);

Response.Write(response);
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(response);
string name = stuff.album.name;
lblInfo.InnerText = name;
```

I'm unable to figure out how to read them properly.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: pls format it readable and then i read it again and maybe you get some help.

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: exception while binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node for `albums` is an array so you must access a position, `0` gets the first album. In your example there's only one album anyway...

```
string name = stuff.topalbums.album[0].name.ToString();
```